# Giving an instance of a class a pointer to a struct

Tags: c++, struct, malloc, new-operator, sse2

I am trying to get SSE functionality in my vector class (I've rewritten it three times so far. :\) and I'm doing the following:

```
#ifndef _POINT_FINAL_H_
#define _POINT_FINAL_H_

#include "math.h"

namespace Vector3D
{

#define SSE_VERSION 3

#if SSE_VERSION >= 2

    #include <emmintrin.h>  // SSE2

    #if SSE_VERSION >= 3

        #include <pmmintrin.h>  // SSE3

    #endif

#else

#include <stdlib.h>

#endif

#if SSE_VERSION >= 2

    typedef union { __m128 vector; float numbers[4]; } VectorData;
    //typedef union { __m128 vector; struct { float x, y, z, w; }; } VectorData;

#else

    typedef struct { float x, y, z, w; } VectorData;

#endif

class Point3D
{

public:

    Point3D();
    Point3D(float a_X, float a_Y, float a_Z);
    Point3D(VectorData* a_Data);
    ~Point3D();

    // a lot of not-so-interesting functions

private:

    VectorData* _NewData();

}; // class Point3D

}; // namespace Vector3D

#endif
```

It works! Hurray! But it's slower than my previous attempt. Boo.

I've determined that my bottle neck is the malloc I'm using to get a pointer to a struct.

```
VectorData* Point3D::_NewData() 
{ 

#if SSE_VERSION >= 2

    return ((VectorData*) _aligned_malloc(sizeof(VectorData), 16)); 

#else

    return ((VectorData*) malloc(sizeof(VectorData))); 

#endif

}
```

One of the main problems with using SSE in a class is that it has to be aligned in memory for it to work, which means overloading the new and delete operators, resulting in code like this:

```
 BadVector* test1 = new BadVector(1, 2, 3);
 BadVector* test2 = new BadVector(4, 5, 6);
 *test1 *= test2;
```

You can no longer use the default constructor and you have to avoid `new` like the plague.

My new approach is basically to have the data external from the class so the class doesn't have to be aligned.

My question is: is there a better way to get a pointer to an (aligned on memory) instance of a struct or is my approach really dumb and there's a much cleaner way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
__declspec( align( 16 ) ) VectorData vd;
```

?

You can also create your own version of operator new as follows

```
void* operator new( size_t size, size_t alignment )
{
     return __aligned_malloc( size, alignment );
}
```

which can then make allocationas follows

```
AlignedData* pData = new( 16 ) AlignedData;
```

to align at a 16 byte boundary.

If thats no help then i may be misunderstanding what you are asking for ...

Comment: You mean _declspec, I suppose ?

Comment: LOL really didn't notice that typo!!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably not expect to get improved performance for single-use vectors. Parallel processing shines brightest when you can combine the parallel processing with some volume, i.e. when processing *many* vectors in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. :O

It was really rather easy. All I had to do was turn

```
VectorData* m_Point;
```

into

```
VectorData m_Point;
```

and my problems are gone, with no need for malloc or aligning.

But I appreciate everyone's help! :D

Comment: Sorry, but I doubt that.  Yes, MS compiler on x86-64 aligns on 16 byte boundary (not for 32 bit platforms).  I doubt that ICC will _always_ align 16 byte on stack if not explicitly said so, too, exactly _because_ it tries to generate really speedy code.  A declspec will be necessary, resp. the corresponding gcc option.